# Which is the most efficient wing form in terms of performance and efficiency?

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft-performance, wing

I am unable to decide as various forms have some or other advantages.

Comment: For high speed, high altitude?  For STOL?  For what application?

Comment: There's no way to answer this question unless you can make it more specific. As you said yourself, different designs have different advantages and disadvantages. If you can explain the aircraft type and how it will be used then you might get a better response.

Comment: Horizontal. Yes, a horizontal wing form is best.

Comment: I suspect this is for a RC model.

Comment: @PeterKämpf, but vertical wings are so much more exciting!

Answer (score 2):

You will never find *the* answer. What is the best car design in performance and efficiency?

A truck is highly efficient (compared to a normal car) when transporting cargo, a jeep will be highly efficient on terrain (compared to a normal car that won't move at all...)

But two simple rules:

- the more V-shaped, the better for high velocity
- the larger, the better for low velocity